# MSBuild Refactoring - When Importing Shared Project, CallTarget doesn't work

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to refactor my MSBuild scripts and have imported a shared build definition by

```
<Import Project="MSBuild.Passolo.targets" />
```

But when I call the custom target from the imported project

```
  <Target Name="AfterCompile">
...
    <CallTarget Targets="MsBuildPassolo" />
...
```

it isn't executed.

Thanks for your answers,

Regards, Marco

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved - have used a wrong Condition, AfterCompile never has been executed.